# why this EuclideanHashFunction class with the same input return different value in java?

Tags: java, hash

when we hash two vwctors with the same input using the following Euclidean hash , it result different output.

```
public EuclideanHash(int dimensions,int w){
            Random rand = new Random();
            this.w = w;
            this.offset = rand.nextInt(w);

            randomProjection = new Vector(dimensions);
            for(int d=0; d<dimensions; d++) {
                //mean 0
                //standard deviation 1.0
                double val = rand.nextGaussian();
                randomProjection.set(d, Math.abs(val));
            }
        }

        public int hash(Vector vector){
            double hashValue = vector.dot(randomProjection)+offset/Double.valueOf(w);
            return (int) Math.round(hashValue);
        }
```

Comment: Because you use a random number (`rand.nextInt(w)`) in the method body...

Comment: random<--- what do you expect?